# Sum of specific columns using mutate and sum with NA values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame `Data`:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | NA | 4 |
| NA | 3 | NA |
| NA | NA | NA |

I want to calculate the sum of columns a to c using `dplyr`s `mutate` function and `sum` to get the following:

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | NA | 4 | 6 |
| NA | 3 | NA | 3 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |

The important thing is for NAs to be treated like 0 basically except when they are all NA then it will return the sum as NA.

I think I can do this:

```
Data<-Data %>%
mutate(d=sum(a,b,c,na.rm=TRUE))
```

The issue is I dont want to list all the variables `a` `b` and `c`, but want to make use of the `:` functionality so that I can list the variables like this `a:c`.

I was thinking of writing the code like this:

```
Data<-Data %>%
mutate(d=sum(a:c,na.rm=TRUE))
```

but this doesn't work. I don't know if I should put a quotation around a and around c?

I swear I've done this million of times before, but I can't find previous code I've used this in and for some reason my brain froze today.

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
df  %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(d=sum(across(a:c),na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Also `rowSums` could be an option

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it simple:

```
 df %>% 
    mutate(
        d = rowSums(across(everything()), na.rm =T),
        d = na_if(d, 0)
    )
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      a     b     c     d
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1     2     4
2     2    NA     4     6
3    NA     3    NA     3
4    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: To clarify, you can also use `:` inside of `across()`, so a more exact solution for the OP would be `d = rowSums(across(a:c), na.rm =T)`

Comment: I mean, you can use any tidyselect verb inside across. I just thought that the scope of tidyselect is a bit off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

You can change everything for any tidyverse selector like matches or starts_with

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~c,
  1L, 1L, 2L,
  2L, NA, 4L,
  NA, 3L, NA,
  NA, NA, NA
  )

df_example |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(d = c_across(everything()) |> sum(na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>       a     b     c     d
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     2     4
#> 2     2    NA     4     6
#> 3    NA     3    NA     3
#> 4    NA    NA    NA     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

A less general solution is to use a rowwise function like rowSums

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~c,
  1L, 1L, 2L,
  2L, NA, 4L,
  NA, 3L, NA,
  NA, NA, NA
  )

df_example |> 
  mutate(d = across(everything()) |> rowSums(na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>       a     b     c     d
#>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     2     4
#> 2     2    NA     4     6
#> 3    NA     3    NA     3
#> 4    NA    NA    NA     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>